# How to iterate over an array containing key values using node js

Tags: node.js

I have 2 arrays

```
test1 = [{"name":"A","age":10},{"name":"B","age":10},{"name":"C","age":10}]
test2 = [{"name":"A","age":10},{"name":"B","age":10},{"name":"D","age":10}]
```

I need to iterate over the arrays based on name and find the diff eleents in each array

i need output like

```
diff_frm_test1 =[{"name":"C","age":10}]
diff_frm_test2 =[{"name":"D","age":10}]
```

I tried using `forEach()` but i am getting combined list.

Comment: you need to use reduce or filter function from es6.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the array based on the names like this:

`test1 .filter(single => single.name === "C")`